# SATA card with good hotswap ability

Tags: windows-server-2008, sata, hotswap

I'm building a Win2k8 backup machine with a removable SATA drive enclosure. The idea is that each week someone will pull out a drive and pop another one in. I need this to work without having to manually rescan disks or reboot. My question is which SATA controller would you recommend that has good hot-swapping ability?

Comment: +1 -- I too would love to see an answer to this!

Answer (score 1):

Any hardware controller from the 3Ware 9xxx series will do fine, for example 9650-SE4LP.